# How to proper delay each 100 mails in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I have 1000 emails and I run job that goes through those 1000 emails and send emails.

I could have:

```
$users = User::all();
$count = 0;
$hours = 0;
foreach($users as $user) {
  if($count % 100 === 0) {
    $hours++;
  }
  Main::to($user->email)->later(now()->addHours($hours), new MyEmail($user));
  $count++;
}
```

I didn't test this yet but I would like to send 100 emails every hour, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You need to sleep somewhere in your `foreach` loop to wait for an hour, and you need your `if` statement to have a different test; right now it will just increment `$hours` which is never checked.

Comment: Lets say I have 1000 users and $count goes and sends first 99 counts with $hours = 0; then 100%100 === 0 equals true, and then update hours for 1 up, then on 200 users do the same. Which means that it would send 100 mails now, 100 in one hour, 100 in two hours ? I don't understand that why it needs to sleep when It can loop through all and set sending with different hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sleep(1);` will not help here, your solution is ok, just keep in mind the first 100 will be delayed for an hour. [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#queueing-mail)

Also as you said `MailTrap` allows only 2 emails in few seconds, you can add hours + few seconds to each `100`, this way each email in `100` batch will be delayed for 1 hour + seconds from 1 to 100;

Or another solution use `--sleep=3` params in `queue:work`, this will process 1 email sleep for 3 seconds and etc.

This will create a queue in (Redis / Database), depends what you are using, and will process them in specified datetime.

```php
$users = User::all();
$count = 0;
$hours = 0;

foreach($users as $user) {

  if($count % 100 === 0) {
    $hours++;
  }

  Mail::to($user)->later(now()->addHours($hours), new MyEmail($user));
  $count++;

}
```

Comment: So if I change hours to -1 it will be now, right? I am using redis, I just tried it with minute but seems like mailtrap is allowing just 2 mails in few seconds. So I will test it with 2 messages pre 2 mins.

Comment: not sure if ou can pass `0` into `now()->addHours($hours)`, ahh now I get it, will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  [sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)
function ,use queue for mail send

```
$users = User::all();
$count = 0;
$hours = 0;
foreach($users as $user) {
  if($count % 100 === 0) {
    $hours++;
  }
  Main::to($user->email)->later(now()->addHours($hours), new MyEmail($user));
  $count++;


  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation why?

Comment: Maybe avoid mail server due to we use sleep function

Comment: I am sorry I am clearly dumb but I don't understand you

Comment: usually there is a waiting time when sending mail, the mail server can also prevent excessive requests

Comment: My english not super maybe I can't explain to you ...you are not dumb ...